# Remove two classes wit jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove both classes `mousemove` and `scrolling` but in my code it only works once.

What do I need to change in my code?

***Fiddle :*** [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/soroush_co/XK8wR/3/)

```
(function (){
    var timer;

    clearTimeout(timer);
    $('body').mousemove(function() {       
        $('body').addClass('mousemove');        
    }); 

    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        $('body').addClass('scrolling');   
    }); 

    timer = setTimeout(function(){$('body').removeClass('scrolling mousemove')}, 2000);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass both the class names separated by a space

```
(function () {
    var timer;

    $('body').mousemove(function () {
        $('body').addClass('mousemove');
        startTimer();
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('body').addClass('scrolling');
        startTimer();
    });

    function startTimer() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        // How To Remove 2 class 'scrolling'&'mousemove' in Body
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('body').removeClass('scrolling mousemove')
        }, 2000);
    }
})();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uZqWh/)

Comment: Thanks men ;) I'm Copy Code To js file an load in Drupal Theme But NOT WORKING! Eror On firebug 
TypeError: $ is not a function
 
$('body').mousemove(function () {

Comment: looks like you missed to include jQuery in the page

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: Are you using Drupal CMS ? I install jQuery_Update module in Drupal And Load jQuery 1.7

Comment: I Change $ To jQuery Fix it ;)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
   ....
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
         $('body').removeClass('scrolling mousemove');
   },2000);
  ...
```

Comment: i think you forgot 2000

Comment: `working One time plase check this` ?? not getting you. http://jsfiddle.net/XK8wR/6/